# I am trying to add products to a shopping cart in mongodb but will get cannot read properties of .find is undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add products to a shopping cart stored in mongodb but a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')" will occur causing it not to add any products to cart. I have spent all day trying to get this to work with no luck any help would be appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const Carts = require('../repo/carts');

// const cartShowTemplate = require('../views/carts/show');

const router = express.Router();
let cart;

router.post('/cart/products', async (req, res) => {
  

  if (!req.session.cartId) {
    cart = await Carts.create({ items: [] });
    req.session.cartId = cart._id;
  } else {
    cart = await Carts.find(req.session.cartId);
  }
  console.log(cart);

    // look thru cart and find item with id property equal to req.body.productId 
      property
    //if item exists increment by 1 and save cart
    //add new product to items array
  const existingItem = cart.items.find(item => item._id  === req.body.productId)
  if (existingItem) {
    existingItem++;
  } else {
    cart.items.push({ id: req.body.productId, quantity: 1 });
  } 
  await Carts.updateOne(cart._id, {
    items: cart.items
  });

  res.send('product added to cart!!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

carts mongodb schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  items: [
    { quantity: Number, _id: String },
  ] 
});

const Carts = new mongoose.model('Carts', cartSchema);

module.exports = Carts;
```

Answer (score 0):

An issue appears to be this line:
`Carts.find(req.session.cartId)`

If you are looking up by id, you should use `findById` not `find`. `findById` is a shortcut to `.find({_id: req.session.cartId})`, when using `find` it will expect a query object.

Comment: that part of the code definitely works the issue lies within const existingItem.

Comment: The error on that line is that it cannot read `find` of undefined. Meaning that `items` is undefined. For items to be undefined, your cart being returned may have no `items` property - but more likely, its returning something unexpected because of the unsupported syntax you are using.